# Determine ESAPI Configuration Properties without Access to Deployment Environment?

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration, esapi

We recently ran a Veracode scan on our Java Spring application for the first time and discovered a lot of security flaws, and the best solution we could determine for many of them was to encode user input via ESAPI.

In this case, because it has been asked, "user input" means, for example, a GUID which comes from a cookie, but Veracode recognizes that cookies can be falsified so cookie content needs to be sanitized ... i.e., using ESAPI encoding functionality as follows:

```
logger.debug("Attempting to broadcast message to all connections with GUID " + ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(guid));
```

We're using Maven, so in order to include ESAPI in our project, all we did was, in our POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And it "just worked."  We literally did nothing else, other than start using `import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;` and we went to town and it was great in local testing.

However, as soon as we went to deployment, it failed with:

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException SecurityConfiguration class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration) CTOR threw exception.
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129) ~[esapi-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.securityConfiguration(ESAPI.java:184) ~[esapi-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:99) ~[esapi-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
```

We do not have any access to the deployment environment, as a third party manages it.  Other StackOverflow questions reporting similar problems have reported that the answer to their questions involved missing  `ESAPI.properties` files.  We did not need to worry about anything like that in our local dev and testing, but I'm worried by the fact that others have reported needing to set one up/set up a path to one.

Is there any way, in our code (which is all we really give to the deployment team), to ensure that ESAPI will run in the deployment environment?

Comment: Have added clarity and answers to your questions.

Comment: First off, 2.0.1 has security vulnerabilities related to crypto.  You should be using 2.1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, most of the other questions here at SO give you the answer.  Here's a comment from the code:

```
/**
 * The reference {@code SecurityConfiguration} manages all the settings used by the ESAPI in a single place. In this reference
 * implementation, resources can be put in several locations, which are searched in the following order:
 * <p>
 * 1) Inside a directory set with a call to SecurityConfiguration.setResourceDirectory( "C:\temp\resources" ).
 * <p>
 * 2) Inside the System.getProperty( "org.owasp.esapi.resources" ) directory.
 * You can set this on the java command line as follows (for example):
 * <pre>
 *      java -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources="C:\temp\resources"
 * </pre>
 * You may have to add this to the start-up script that starts your web server. For example, for Tomcat,
 * in the "catalina" script that starts Tomcat, you can set the JAVA_OPTS variable to the {@code -D} string above.
 * <p>
 * 3) Inside the {@code System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/.esapi"} directory (supported for backward compatibility) or
 * inside the {@code System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/esapi"} directory.
 * <p>
 * 4) The first ".esapi" or "esapi" directory on the classpath. (The former for backward compatibility.)
 * <p>
 * Once the Configuration is initialized with a resource directory, you can edit it to set things like master
 * keys and passwords, logging locations, error thresholds, and allowed file extensions.
 * <p>
 * WARNING: Do not forget to update ESAPI.properties to change the master key and other security critical settings.
 *
 * @author Jeff Williams (jeff.williams .at. aspectsecurity.com) <a href="http://www.aspectsecurity.com">Aspect Security</a>
 * @author Jim Manico (jim .at. manico.net) <a href="http://www.manico.net">Manico.net</a>
 * @author Kevin Wall (kevin.w.wall .at. gmail.com)
 */
```

In your case, for the deployment command that will run your web app, give the deployment team a directory according to the java Runtime property listed in section 2 here.  They will need to add it to whatever script/command is triggered that spins up your web container.